# emacs slime: Whats the equivalent of the up arrow in shells?

Tags: lisp, slime

When I type something wrong in dos/linux and it yells at me I can push the up arrow and then modify my line - maybe it was missing a '-' or something.  I just installed lispbox and up arrow moves the cursor up the REPL history.  How do i put on the current line the last line I entered.

So like I type

```
+ 3 2
```

But obviously I meant

```
(+ 3 2)
```

How do I get it to say "+ 3 2" so I can just push "Home", "(", "End", ")"?

Or is there some MUCH easier M-x waaahFIXIT command for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
(slime-repl-previous-input)
```

which is bound to

```
M-p
```

by default. (Meta is normally the Alt key)

M-p / M-n is standard for going backwards / forwards through history in emacs - it also works in the minibuffer too

Comment: Is there a way to get previous input inserted automatically into another form I have started typing? For instance, `(list <key combo for previous input to be inserted here>)`